# Replacing variables in config file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write code to check config file wether it contains certain UserParameters and if not to add them to the file. I feel like my code is definetly wrong on so many levels and I'm out of ideas.

```
$s1 = 'a'
$s2 = 'b'
$s3 = 'c'
$s4 = 'd'
$s5 = 'e'
$s6 = 'f'
$s7 = 'g'
$s8 = 'h'
$scripts = $s1, $s2, $s3, $s4, $s5, $s6, $s7, $s8

foreach ($element in $scripts) {
    if ("(UserParameter=$element)" -notmatch $config) {
        Get-Content $File $element -replace '^(UserParameter=)',"`$1$($element)"
    } else {
        Add-Content $File "UserParameter=$element"
    }
```

I don't exactly know how to make sure that there will be something like:

```
UserParameter=a
UserParameter=b
...
UserParameter=h
```

**Edit:**

Config I currently have
https://pastebin.com/BdwH53QZ

State of config I want to attain:
https://pastebin.com/6f0xe2k3

Added new lines at the end of the file.

```
UserParameter=windowsdisk.discovery, powershell -NoProfile -File discover_PerfMon_PhysicalDisk.ps1
UserParameter=vfs.fs.partition.label[*], powershell -NoProfile -File get_volume_label.ps1 $1
UserParameter=psh.rds.empty.session.detect, powershell -NoProfile -File rds_empty_session_detect.ps1
UserParameter=psh.pki.rootca.thumb.count[*], powershell -NoProfile -Command "(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\$1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count"
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? it LOOKS like you got stuck on an idea that doesn't do what you actually want ... [*grin*]

Comment: I'm trying to automate script for changing zabbix config file. I have basic parameters down, and now I need to add UserParameters... for now there are 8 UserParams to be added. but I need to be able to add more and check wether they are already present in the config file. If they are present, then skip otherwise add them to the file.

Comment: do all the user parameters have the same name [as shown in your sample]? perhaps you should add a sample of the file you are checking and show what you want to do to it ...

Comment: The file should have lines like this:
UserParameter=windowsdisk.discovery, powershell -NoProfile -File discover_PerfMon_PhysicalDisk.ps1
UserParameter=vfs.fs.partition.label, powershell -NoProfile -File  get_volume_label.ps1 $1

Comment: use `Get-Content` to read the file in as an array of strings. find each line that starts with `UserParameter=`. compare what comes after than with one of your items to check for, if it is not there - add it. ///// i am not good at such abstract stuff, so to get more specific i would need to see a sample input file, a list of things to check, and the expected output from the two - added in your Original Post, since it is nearly unreadable otherwise. [*grin*]

Comment: Hi, JD, I read comments three times and still not getting what are you trying to do, in the current state, the purpose is unreachable, please edit the post and clarify the request, thanks.  `check config file wether it contains certain UserParameters` So you are investigating, if eg. in case of `$s1= 'a'` config file contains `something=a` ?

Comment: Hi Vodnik, I've added pastebins of configs... $s1-$s8 is my attempt at arraying variables for UserParameters... correct I'm trying to check wether UserParameters=a if not add Userparameters=a.... then do the same for 'b' then 'c' ad infinum

Comment: @JDHellequin - thank you for the added info! [*grin*] ///// you can do what i mentioned earlier - use `Get-Content` to read the file, iterate thru it, check for `UserParameter=` and then compare the part on the right of the `=` with the entries in your list of things that must be there.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey my knowledge of Powershell is selftaught madness over past yesterday [tacticalfaceplant] //// eg. count me as something akin to total beginner

Comment: Good, thank you for clarification, now its already what we can deal with :) Actually you should paste examples directly into post, but better like that, than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your UserParameters are quite complex and comparing them with a file would fail with even subtle differences in white space I'm in doubt your approach works.

I suggest to find some Regular Expressions to filter if a given UserParameter is already present.

If you choose PowerShell it's unevitable to learn this script language or to delegate to someone else.

You could try something along these lines:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\24\SO_55827904.ps1
$UserParameters = @"
UserParameter=windowsdisk.discovery, powershell -NoProfile -File discover_PerfMon_PhysicalDisk.ps1
UserParameter=vfs.fs.partition.label[*], powershell -NoProfile -File get_volume_label.ps1 $1
UserParameter=psh.rds.empty.session.detect, powershell -NoProfile -File rds_empty_session_detect.ps1
UserParameter=psh.pki.rootca.thumb.count[*], powershell -NoProfile -Command "(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\$1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count"
"@ -split '\r?\n'

ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path X:\path -Filter *zabbix_agent.conf)){
    $FileContent = Get-Content $File -raw
    ForEach ($UserParam in $UserParameters){
        if($FileContent -notmatch [RegEx]::Escape($UserParam)){
           Add-Content -Path $File.FullName -Value $UserParam
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to adapt `-Path` and `-Filter` to your environment.

Comment: I'm practically in no choice situation... I have to learn it... what I've written so far is what I've self-taught from function descriptions and pure luck... With some small adaptations your code works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be this one:

```
$file = 'D:\zabbix_agent.conf'

# create an array of userparameters to add if not already present
$userParams = 'UserParameter=windowsdisk.discovery, powershell -NoProfile -File discover_PerfMon_PhysicalDisk.ps1',
              'UserParameter=vfs.fs.partition.label[*], powershell -NoProfile -File get_volume_label.ps1 $1',
              'UserParameter=vfs.fs.partition.label[*], powershell -NoProfile -File get_volume_label.ps1 $2',
              'UserParameter=psh.rds.empty.session.detect, powershell -NoProfile -File rds_empty_session_detect.ps1',
              'UserParameter=psh.pki.rootca.thumb.count[*], powershell -NoProfile -Command "(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\$1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count"'

# read the file as a string array
$content = Get-Content -Path $file
# remember the original lines count so we know if parameters were added or not
$originalCount = $content.Count

# get a sub-array of all lines from $content that start with 'UserParameter='
$currentParams = @($content | Where-Object { $_ -match '^UserParameter=' })
if ($currentParams.Count -eq 0) {
    # if the config file did not have any 'UserParameter=' lines, we add the whole $userParams array to the content
    $content += $userParams
}
else {
    # there were 'UserParameter=' lines found, so filter out all required parameters that need to be added
    $addThese = @($userParams | Where-Object { $currentParams -notcontains $_ })
    if ($addThese.Count) { $content += $addThese }
}

if ($originalCount -ne $content.Count) {
    Write-Host "Writing new Zabbix configuration file." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Set-Content -Path $file -Value $content
}
else {
    Write-Host "File '$file' already contained the required user parameters." -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my version. [*grin*] i made two files from your samples. one with NO UserParameter lines and one with two such lines. the code below checks to see if there are ANY such lines ... if not, it adds all of them. if *yes*, it adds the ones that from the list of needed values that are missing.

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp\JDHellequin_-_sample - *.txt'
$Prefix = 'UserParameter='

$NeededParamList = @(
    'windowsdisk.discovery, powershell -NoProfile -File discover_PerfMon_PhysicalDisk.ps1'
    'vfs.fs.partition.label[*], powershell -NoProfile -File get_volume_label.ps1 $1'
    'psh.rds.empty.session.detect, powershell -NoProfile -File rds_empty_session_detect.ps1'
    'psh.pki.rootca.thumb.count[*], powershell -NoProfile -Command "(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\$1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count"'
    )

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    $TargetLines = @(Get-Content -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName).
        Where({
            $_.StartsWith($Prefix)
            }).
        ForEach({
            $_.Split('=')[1]
            })


    foreach ($NPL_Item in $NeededParamList)
        {
        $NewLine = '{0}{1}' -f $Prefix, $NPL_Item
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($TargetLines))
            {
            Add-Content -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName -Value $NewLine
            }
            else
            {
            if ($NPL_Item -notin $TargetLines)
                {
                Add-Content -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName -Value $NewLine
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in each case, the added-to file has four lines that match the required items in the `$NeededParamList` collection.

Comment: Thanks for your version of the solution... I've implemented LotPings's version as this one is bit overwhelming for me [_facedesk_]

Comment: @JDHellequin - you are most welcome! [*grin*] the one by LotPings is a very similar approach - but his makes a collection of what to add while mine adds them one-at-a-time. his comments are MUCH better than mine ... [*grin*]

Comment: I wonder wether it's possible to catch malformed param (like missing character or number)... maybe sort of charcount? I wanted to fully use RegEX, but my boss doesn't really understand them so I'm banished from using them

Comment: @JDHellequin - using regex on those parameters ... would be hellish. [*grin*] the embedded special chars `.[]*` are truly icky to work with. that is why i stuck with `-eq` instead of trying to use `-match`.

Comment: I'm thinking about `if ($($ConfigFileContent | measure -character -ignorewhitespace) -notmatch $($userparam | measure -character -ignore whitespace))` or something along those lines

Comment: @JDHellequin - that seems ... needlessly roundabout to me. do a straight `-eq` test on the items and use an array of the parameter values to test against.

Comment: I've tried this:  `foreach( $param in $(Get-content $configfile | Select-String -Pattern '^(UserParameter=).*')) {
      if($UserParameters -ne $param) {
      (Get-content $configfile -RAW) -replace '$param','' | Set-Content $configfile
      }
} ` but if i malform any of the lines in configfile, it won't delete them... where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @JDHellequin - this is a new problem and otta be handled in a new question. [*grin*] ///// that aside, one gotcha with `Select-String` is that is does NOT return a simple string - it returns a match object. you may need to convert that to a simple string to make it useful in your other stages.

Comment: I am so done with this, but it's working... https://github.com/JDHarlequin/zabbix_scripts

Comment: @JDHellequin - nice! it works ... and that is always the _primary_ point ... [*grin*]